# How to turn off Atom's url highlighting?

Tags: url, editor, atom-editor

I found out that when editing documents in Atom, URLs are automatically highlighted. Is it possible to turn this behavior off and display URLs as ordinary strings?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just disable the `language-hyperlink` package.

Settings > Packages > Language Hyperlink > Disable